# Sending email to a specific list of contacts

Tags: crm, bronto

I have a list of contacts (List A) that I would like to send a particular email to. However, the issue here is that the contacts in this List A are present in the Bronto Contacts database already, and I have no way of applying segmentation so that I get the same contacts as the ones in List A.

Is there a way I can send these contacts an email from Bronto?

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to do this programmatically, Bronto has an [API](https://help.bronto.com/bmp/concept/c_api_overview.html) that you can use to look up the contacts, as well as send a message. Otherwise you'd likely have to create a new list that mirrors List A (which would be very time-consuming - but can also be done programmatically via their API).